# How to output files in same folder where the command is executed in perl

Tags: perl

I have `fastq_trimmer_command_line.pl`. It has `chmod 755` and is located in a directory in the `PATH`. I am running this script from the directory in which I want the output (`~/data/output`), and input files are in different folder (`~/data`).

The command:

```
~/data/output$ fastq_trimmer_command_line.pl -f ../r1.fastq -r ../r2.fastq -c 22
```

`fastq_trimmer_command_line.pl`:

```
...important details omitted...
open OUT_R1, ">", "$R1_file-trimmed.fq";
```

The output file is created in folder `~/data`, where the input file is. How do I create `r1.fastq--trimmed.fq` in `~/data/output`, the directory from which the command was executed?

Comment: The default for any command is to interpret relative file names relative to the current directory, i.e. exactly what you seem to be asking.

Comment: Need some clarification:  Are you asking how to do what you ask from within the Perl script "script.pl" or from an O/S command-line?  If you are asking to do it from the Perl script, then I agree with toolic that showing the relevant Perl code would be helpful.  Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, if the input file is `../r1.fastq`, you want the output file to be `r1.fastq-trimmed.fq`.

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

my $input_qfn = '../r1.fastq';
my $output_qfn = basename($input_qfn) . '-trimmed.fq';
```

Comment: It is not where the executable is. Please check  the modified question. I tried to make this more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Despite your revisions, this answer is still correct.